# How do I remove the Header and footer "area" from a word document?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2013

I have a document, which has a normal cover. When I try to resize (upscale) a word in the first line after the header, this happens:

[image]

Now I do not want the header and footer deleted, what I want is to literally remove the header/footer function so I can make use of that unused space in the top/bottom of the page, I tried regulating the ruler but it doesn't make any difference at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to change the *page margins* (which include the *top margin* and *bottom margin*).  This is described in several places, with tutorials.

Here is a useful one:

- *[Change page margins](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Change-page-margins-acf0317f-86ab-4bd7-a6a3-75df6234fac3)*, specifically the section starting

> On the Page Layout tab, in the Page Setup group, click Margins.

and then

> At the bottom of the Margins gallery, click Custom Margins. The Page Setup dialog box appears.

You can adjust the margins there.  But keep in mind that printers also require margins, so there are limits to the amount of space you can use.

Comment: that's what the ruler is for, didn't make a single difference, I tried even changing the paragraph margins, still cut out.

Comment: I have have 2003 "here", and can set the height of the top and bottom margins to 0.1 inches, which is reasonably "gone".  Reading about later versions (other than going to office...), suggests that the Header and Footer gallery offers more choices.

Comment: sadly not, but i had to force my way in without removing those unused space, i guess the "Write wherever you want" rule in the newer versions is still handicaped for now, thanks for your help

Comment: In the 2003 version, the dialog lets me shrink the header/footer to the single line paragraph, and changing that line's font properties down to 8pts was as far as I could go.  (I tried deleting the paragraph, but it ignored my attempt).